# Correct use of unique_ptr for parent / child relationship

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I'm relatively new to C++ and smart pointers as I primarily use C#.  I've been through heaps of questions here about the correct usage of unique_ptrs and I think I understand that smart pointers are all about ownership and who will take responsibility for deleting the memory held by the pointer when it goes out of scope.

That said, it the below example correct? Parent will always be the owner of it's children and manage the child's lifetime.  However, if another class needs to hold a child, and will always live less than the child, is it ok for that class to hold a raw pointer to the child?

```
class ChildTypeA;
class ChildTypeB;

class Parent
{
public:
    ChildTypeA* createChildA()
    {
        ChildTypeA *aPtr = new ChildTypeA(/* pass this to constructor */);
        typeAChildren.push_back(std::unique_ptr<ChildTypeA>(aPtr));

        return aPtr;
    }

    ChildTypeB* createChildB()
    {
        ChildTypeB *aPtr = new ChildTypeB(/* pass this to constructor */);
        typeBChildren.push_back(std::unique_ptr<ChildTypeB>(aPtr));

        return aPtr;
    }

    void somethingCalledByChildA()
    {}

    void somethingCalledByChildB()
    {}

private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ChildTypeA>> typeAChildren;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ChildTypeB>> typeBChildren;
};

class ChildTypeA
{
public:
    ChildTypeA() {} // parameterless constructor purely for single file example
    ChildTypeA(Parent *parent) : owningParent(parent)
    {}

    void notifyParentOfSomethingA()
    {
        owningParent->somethingCalledByChildA();
    }

    void doSomethingOnThisChild()
    {}

private:
    Parent *owningParent;

};

class ChildTypeB
{
public:
    ChildTypeB() {} // parameterless constructor purely for single file example
    ChildTypeB(Parent *parent) : owningParent(parent)
    {}

    void notifyParentOfSomethingB()
    {
        owningParent->somethingCalledByChildB();
    }

private:
    Parent *owningParent;

};

class SomeOtherClassThatWantsAChildAAndWillAlwaysLiveShorterThanChildA
{
public:
    SomeOtherClassThatWantsAChildAAndWillAlwaysLiveShorterThanChildA(ChildTypeA *child) : childNotOwnedByMe(child)
    {}

    void doSomething()
    {  
       childNotOwnedByMe->doSomethingOnThisChild();
    }

private:
    ChildTypeA * childNotOwnedByMe;
};
```

So then code somewhere would do something like:

```
ChildTypeA *a = someInstanceOfParent->createChildA();
auto x = new SomeOtherClassThatWantsAChildAAndWillAlwaysLiveShorterThanChildA(a);
```

Comment: You might want to consider using a reference instead of a pointer.

Comment: if you just observe something, raw pointer does the job. This includes the children holding a raw pointer to parent.

Comment: I did consider passing a Parent reference to ChildA / B, but have read on another post here that reference class member can be problematic, especially if I ever need to change the owningParent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example is correct, `unique_ptr` is all about ownership, and this doesn't prevent referencing the raw pointer from other class, the things that need to be kept in mind are:

1) Check the raw pointer before using.

2) Don't invoke `delete` on the raw pointer.

Comment: Thanks!  Might finally be understanding this ownership thing with smart pointers.